# Can't pass letters to php via ajax but numbers are ok

Tags: php, ajax

For some reason I can only successfully pass integers from my ajax function to my php document but letters return nothing. I can't figure out why.

For example with the four `textarea` filled out with 1, 2, 3, 4 returns `12341` but filling them out with A, B, C, D and the PHP-script fails (it does trigger a DB-response) and the `success`-function of the ajax returns nothing. Not actually certain anything's been passed but the array appears in the Network-tab of Operas developer tools

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div><textarea name="answerRight" placeholder="Correct" rows="1" required=""></textarea></div>
            <div><textarea name="answerWrong" placeholder="Wrong" rows="1" required=""></textarea></div>
            <div><textarea name="answerWrong" placeholder="Wrong" rows="1" required=""></textarea></div>
            <div><textarea name="answerWrong" placeholder="Wrong" rows="1" required=""></textarea></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="qNo" value="'.$i.'"> //Number from php in a previous stage
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode($_POST['arrayCombined'], true);
    include('dbconnect.php');

    echo $data[0][0];

    echo $data[1][0];
    echo $data[1][1];
    echo $data[1][2];

    echo $data[2][0];
?>
```

Aaand the JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submitQuestionnaire").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
                
            //Arrays of the forms
            var answerRightArray = new Array();
            $("textarea[name='answerRight']").each(function(){
                answerRightArray.push($(this).val());
            })
            var answerWrongArray = new Array();
            $("textarea[name='answerWrong']").each(function(){
                answerWrongArray.push($(this).val());
            })
            var qNumbers = new Array();
            $("input[name='qNo']").each(function(){
                qNumbers.push($(this).val());
            })
            //Combine arrays
            var arrayCombined = [answerRightArray, answerWrongArray, qNumbers];

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/insertion.php",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {"arrayCombined": JSON.stringify(arrayCombined)},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(arrayCombined);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, for each test case, what is the exact data that gets sent to the server?

Comment: @David Hi. I'm not entirely sure where to look, but the network tab in Opera shows POST-request to insertion.php with the text: `arrayCombined: [["A"],["B","C","D"],["1"]]` for the one case, and `arrayCombined: [["1"],["2","3","4"],["1"]]` for the other.

Comment: Changing the php to `<? php echo "Hello!"; ?>` doesn't yield any success function either for the letters but still work fine with the integers. I'm assuming the ajax function is off somewhere

Comment: ..and `window.alert(arrayCombined);` before the ajax prints the same as the `console.log` but works with letters so now I'm still confused

Comment: If you add an error handler, you'd likely see an error telling you that the response from the server isn't json, as you instructed jquery it should be.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you Kevin. Yes I figured that out after a few hours of reading. I had misconcepted the use of the `dataType:` line - thought it was necessary to send JSON and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `dataType: "JSON",` from the ajax-function and keeping `JSON.stringify` seems to have done the trick. I'm assuming, and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, this is because I'm handling it as json in the php file and then not encoding it before sending it back, so the ajax `success` function doesn't receive the data it expects.

Comment: See Kevin B’s comment to your question.